# Unauthorized Access in NPM Proxy repository in Nexus

Tags: npm, nexus

I have created a proxy of NPM repository (https://registry.npmjs.org/) in my local machine.

But when I install the [bower module of node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower) using the proxy repository by the command:
    npm install bower

it's giving "unauthorized access"

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Nexus setup you might have to configure security to be able to allow downloads. This is documented in the [NPM chapter of the Nexus](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/npm-deploying-packages.html) documentation.

Comment: When i use curl command with -u then its getting downloaded.I think nodejs is not authenticating properly

Comment: it is solved by  granting read access to all npm repositories for anonymous user.But this is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add `always-auth=true` in your .npmrc ! Referring to the [documentation](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/npm-configuring.html)

Comment: Yep, always-auth=true in .npmrc helped!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to activate npm Bearer Token Realm in nexus administration panel.